# How to concatenate a range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 2003, is there a way to combine values in a cell range, with a comma separator in between, without typing the individual cell references
for example concatenate A86:A90 and concatenate A193:A198 with comma separator between each individual cell; to get the same result as

=(A86&","A87&","&A88&","A89&","&A90&","
&A193&","&A194&","&A195&","&A196&","&A197&","&A198)

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-rows-in-a-column-into-one-cell-in-excel) and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried that function in excel 2003, but it gave me error  #name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you wish to concatenate **blocks** of cells, consider using the following *User Defined Function*:

```
Public Function KonKat(ParamArray rngs()) As String
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, rr As Range, s As String

    For i = LBound(rngs) To UBound(rngs)
        Set rr = rngs(i)
        For Each r In rr
            If s = "" Then
                s = r.Text
            Else
                s = s & "," & r.Text
            End If
        Next r
    Next i

    KonKat = s
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=KonKat(B1:D1,C3:E3)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

For specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

For specifics on `ParamArray` see:

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**